# How can i use "break" properly into a while loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this program but i get that error massage: 'break' not properly in loop. I've searched for some answers and the reason for the mistake, break cannot be used outside a loop statement.

But as you see bellow, i'm trying to use "break" in a while loop. I'm new to programming, so please don't mind the simplicity of the code.

```
import random

x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")

while x == "s":
        print("Nº dado:", random.randrange(1,7))
        x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")
else:
    break
```

I expect to shut down the running programm after a user enter "N".

Comment: you should put the `break` statement inside the `while` not the `else` block.

Comment: You don't need a `break` for that. With your code, your loop is going to stop when the user inputs something different to 'S', like 'N', for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly speaking, the `else` statement is executed if you exit a block normally, by hitting the loop condition, in your case when `x == "s"` is `False`. It is not executed if you `break` or `return` out of a block, or raise an exception.

Therefore, there is no point putting a `break` statement inside an `else` block of a loop because the `break` statements are meant to terminate a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You don´t have to add break in this case, typing N will override the condition of while. Just remove the break statement.

Answer (score 0):

"break" should only be used within a while loop. Are you trying to stop execution of the program? if so, use `exit()`

For example:

```
import random

x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")

while x == "s":
        print("Nº dado:", random.randrange(1,7))
        x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")
else:
    print("Input was not equal to s")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop ends when you go out of the indented segment, so since the indentation changed, the else statement isn't in the while statement, which is why it causes the issue.

To get the behaviour you require, you'd want something like

```
while x == "s":
    print("Nº dado:", random.randrange(1,7))
    x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")
if x == "n":
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

While inherently will keep looping as long as the condition is true. As such, in your example, your loop will continue until x == "s", and it will then break out automatically.

```
#Execute code as long as x is "s"
while x == "s":
        print("Nº dado:", random.randrange(1,7))
        #Get new input for x
        x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")
        #At this point, we've reached end of while loop, it'll check the condition again
        #If x is still "s", it'll start over at the print line
        #If x is no longer "s" (our condition fails), it stops looping
```

A break is only necessary if you need an additional exit condition, for example if you just want to wait for up to 3 inputs, and then break,

```
i = 0
while x == "s":
        i = i + 1
        print("Nº dado:", random.randrange(1,7))
        x = input("Rolar dado? Insira : S/N")
        if i == 3:
            break
```